# Zoom in on current mouse position in OpenGL using GLM functionality

Tags: c++, opengl, zooming, glm-math

I'm despairing of the task to zoom in on the current mouse position in OpenGL. I've tried a lot of different things and read other posts on this, but I couldn't adapt the possible solutions to my specific problem. So as far as I understood it, you'll have to get the current window coordinates of the mouse curser, then unproject them to get world coordinates and finally translate to those world coordinates.

To find the current mouse positions, I use the following code in my GLUT mouse callback function every time the right mouse button is clicked.

```
if(button == 2)
{
    mouse_current_x = x;
    mouse_current_y = y;
...
```

Next up, I unproject the current mouse positions in my display function before setting up the ModelView and Projection matrices, which also seems to work perfectly fine:

```
// Unproject Window Coordinates
float mouse_current_z;
glReadPixels(mouse_current_x, mouse_current_y, 1, 1, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL_FLOAT, &mouse_current_z);
glm::vec3 windowCoordinates = glm::vec3(mouse_current_x, mouse_current_y, mouse_current_z);
glm::vec4 viewport = glm::vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, (float)width, (float)height);
glm::vec3 worldCoordinates = glm::unProject(windowCoordinates, modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix, viewport);
printf("(%f, %f, %f)\n", worldCoordinates.x, worldCoordinates.y, worldCoordinates.z);
```

Now the translation is where the trouble starts. Currently I'm drawing a cube with dimensions (dimensionX, dimensionY, dimensionZ) and translate to the center of that cube, so my zooming happens to the center point as well. I'm achieving zooming by translating in z-direction (dolly):

```
// Set ModelViewMatrix
modelViewMatrix = glm::mat4(1.0); // Start with the identity as the transformation matrix
modelViewMatrix = glm::translate(modelViewMatrix, glm::vec3(0.0, 0.0, -translate_z)); // Zoom in or out by translating in z-direction based on user input 
modelViewMatrix = glm::rotate(modelViewMatrix, rotate_x, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); // Rotate the whole szene in x-direction based on user input
modelViewMatrix = glm::rotate(modelViewMatrix,  rotate_y, glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)); // Rotate the whole szene in y-direction based on user input
modelViewMatrix = glm::rotate(modelViewMatrix, -90.0f, glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)); // Rotate the camera by 90 degrees in negative x-direction to get a frontal look on the szene
modelViewMatrix = glm::translate(modelViewMatrix, glm::vec3(-dimensionX/2.0f, -dimensionY/2.0f, -dimensionZ/2.0f)); // Translate the origin to be the center of the cube
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, globalMatricesUBO);
glBufferSubData(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, sizeof(glm::mat4), sizeof(glm::mat4), glm::value_ptr(modelViewMatrix));
glBindBuffer(GL_UNIFORM_BUFFER, 0);
```

I tried to replace the translation to the center of the cube by translating to the worldCoordinates vector, but this didn't work. I also tried to scale the vector by width or height.
Am I missing out on some essential step here?

Comment: I think, after translating to the center of the cube, you should come back to the origin and then translate in z

Comment: The zooming to the center is working alright with the code posted above. Now I'd like to zoom to some arbitrary position and the question is how to achieve this.

Comment: You want to zoom in a direction different than 0,0,0 without rotation of the camera? then you will have to jump the camera to the new position so that it is still looking at the same "z" direction. The more natural zoom will be the camera to retain its world position but change the point it is looking at. This requires rotation. You may read about yaw,pitch,rotate.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this is meant...could this rotation automatically be achieved by glm::lookAt() function? Otherwise how do I know the necessary rotation angles?

Comment: You may take a look at a couple of articles http://celestialcoding.com/opengl-147/opengl-ground-up-tutorial-6-mouse-based-camera-rotation/?PHPSESSID=mjtq65vsm6oic63icbg28p7od3
and http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/camera.html

Comment: Was wondering whether you got an answer to that question and if you did whether you could post it or not

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this won't work in your case.  But to me this seems like the best way to handle this. Use glulookat() to look at the xyz position of the mouse click that you have already found.  Then change the gluPerspective() to a smaller angle of view to achieve the actual zoom.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to achieve zooming by changing the perspective, so that doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: @Schnigges: Then your question is improperly named. "Zoom" means "change the FOV". If you want to "zoom" by moving the camera, that's not "zoom" anymore; that's *moving the camera*.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, but I think you can interpret this camera movement as zoom whatsoever. That's why I said "I'm achieving zooming by translating in z-direction (dolly)".

Comment: But assuming I'd use gluLookat or glm::lookAt to do this...how do I have to scale the lookat parameter vector of those functions? If I just use the worldCoordinates vector as it comes from the unProject function, the result is that nothing's beeing rendered.

Comment: I suggest in the beginning you imagine the interaction of the objects.The camera is an object that has world position, and the look-at,up and right/left vectors form a new space from which the world is rendered. The vectors of its coordinate system are normalized. They are just directions. To zoom, you move the camera position towards the point you are zooming, which is an object for example. The zoom is in the direction you are looking at. Once you imagine it little math will help to pack it up.